# Cygwin packages not workiing after installing with pact on Babun (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, cygwin, babun, pact, pact-ruby

Same as https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/702

I first noticed this when I installed `pact install dig`. `which dig` returns the binary's location, but it does nothing:

```
{ ~ }  » dig github.com                                                               ~ 127
{ ~ }  »
```

I later realized no packages work after install. I've tried `php` and `ruby` (`gem`).

Ideas on how to troubleshoot Cygwin? I'm assuming that's where the problem is. It's installed in %HOMEPATH%/.babun/cygwin

---

Update: when I try ruby or php from Window's cmd.exe, I get an error dialog titled "Entry Point Not Found": The procedure entry point __locale_ctype_ptr could not be located in the dynamic link library ... .babun\cygwin\bin\cygruby220.dll or cygphp.dll, respectively.

I looked it up but haven't found any useful info.

I should also add that I just realized I may have initially installed Babun on Windows 7 (before upgrading to 10), but the current one I have I completely re-installed on Windows 10, so I'm hoping that's not an issue.

Comment: Install cygwin in the proper way. `https://www.cygwin.com/` . I presume babun is messing up the package versions and mixing incompatible release of upstream packages.

Comment: I checked/tried that. Babun has it's own pre-configured copy of Cygwin so a separate install of cyg doesn't interact with Babun at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had so much trouble when installing Perl, Python, and gcc/g++ with pact (not going to get too heavy on the details) that I ended up just saying screw it, downloaded an x86 cygwin installer, and pointed it to where babun keeps its cygwin files which for me was %USERPROFILE%.babun\cygwin. That worked for me. Now I can use Babun without any weirdness. BTW, I'm on Windows 7, but I'm presuming it won't make much of a difference.